# Can't access Ubuntu shared folder from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, smb

I couldn't access an Ubuntu shared folder from one of my Windows 10 computers, from the other side, I could access from another windows 10 and 7.
I tried with all the smb versions and always had the same issue which is a weird authentication message.

[image: Error message]

Comment: Have you tried writing `[UbuntuHostname]\hrmadmin` in your usernamefield?

Comment: I does't work too

Comment: did you set the samba password? It's different from Ubuntu password

Comment: Yes I did, and I said that I could access from too many other devices.